# How to use specified Dbus address in RHEL Docker container?

Tags: docker, containers, rhel, dbus, almalinux

I am working on enabling some keyring related tests in the pipeline, but right now having some issue with the secret-tool. I am able to go through this [How do you enable the secret-tool command (backed by gnome-keyring, libsecret and dbus) in a headless CentOS Docker container?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473528/how-do-you-enable-the-secret-tool-command-backed-by-gnome-keyring-libsecret-an#:%7E:text=docker%20run%20--privileged%20-d%20-v%20%2Fsys%2Ffs%2Fcgroup%3A%2Fsys%2Ffs%2Fcgroup%3Aro%20--name%20centos-systemd,where%20the%20automatic%20keyring%20is%20created%20%23%201.)
I want to specify my `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` to `/run/user/$UID/bus`, but it says `secret-tool: Could not connect: Connection refused`. What does it make the difference when `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-xxxx,guid=xxxx` and `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$UID/bus`?

I have created the directory and make sure the container pipeline has the access `sudo chown $UID /run/user`, so not sure why it's complaining about Connection refused.

I am using AlmaLinux docker container image
`docker run --privileged -it almalinux:8 /bin/bash`.

Any ideas? Thank you.

I also tried to override dbus.conf with `<listen>unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus</listen>` 
I get the message 'Failed to start message bus: Failed to bind socket "/run/user/1000/bus": Address already in use'